# Adding maintenance plan in SQL Server with commands

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to add a maintenance plan on an SQL server using SQL or a C# library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at the following SPs in msdb.
MSDN... [Database Maintenance Plan Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190341.aspx)

- sp_add_maintenance_plan
- sp_delete_maintenance_plan_db
- sp_add_maintenance_plan_db
- sp_delete_maintenance_plan_job
- sp_add_maintenance_plan_job
- sp_help_maintenance_plan
- sp_delete_maintenance_plan

Comment: Alan hi! using those commands, how can i actually build maintenance plan to backup db?

Comment: I don't remember how i did it exactly, but i run a trace while i was doing one with management studio and checked how things were done by the GUI. Good luck!